# how to get a passed data from the url in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Hi i have this data passed in the url
http://www.test.com/dashboard/john-doe

i want to get the page when i enter http://www.test.com/dashboard/john-doe
john doe is a name from the database i retrieve when the users can login.

so dashboard is a controller then how will i able to get the page if i passed a data john-doe next to dashboard controller? can someone help me figured this thing out? Any help is muchly appreicated this is my controller below

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Dashboard extends CI_Controller {
  public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('users_model', 'um');

        $sessionData = $this->session->userdata('loggedIn');
        $this->data['id'] = $sessionData['userID'];

        if(!$this->session->userdata('loggedIn')){
      redirect('login');
    }

  }

    public function index($slug){
        echo $slug; exit;
        $this->data['title'] = 'Dashboard | test';
        $this->data['menu'] = 'dashboard';
        //get CustomerInfo
        $this->data['getCustomerInfo'] = $this->um->getCustomerInfo($this->data['id']);


        $this->template_lib->set_view('templateLogIn', 'dashboard', $this->data,'',$this->data);
    }
}
```

Comment: show your code and effort

Comment: i added my code above

Comment: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

Comment: Codeigniter.com user guide codeigniter 2 routing http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/routing.html not sure why people still give old ellislab user guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `index` function is loaded by default if the second segment of the URI is empty. If you have parameters you need to define a route:

```
$route['dashboard/(:any)'] = "dashboard/index/$1";
```